# SQLAlchemy eager loading multiple relationships

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy supports eager load for relationship, it is basically a `JOIN` statement. However, if a model has two or more relationships, it could be a very huge join. For example,

```
class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    orders = relationship('Order', backref='product', cascade='all')
    tags = relationship('Tag', secondary=product_tag_map)

class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'order'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    date = Column(TIMESTAMP, default=datetime.now())

class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    tag_type = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    tag_value = Column(String(255), nullable=False)

q = session.query(Product).join(User.addresses)\
    .options(joinedload(Product.orders))\
    .options(joinedload(Product.tags)).all()
```

The performance of this query is really bad, because the `JOIN` of `Order` and `Tag` will generate a huge table. But the `Order` and `Tag` has no relationship in here, so they should not be `JOIN`. It should be two separated queries. And because the session has some level of caching, so I changed my query to this.

```
session.query(Product).join(Product.order) \
    .options(joinedload(Product.tags)).all()

q = session.query(Product).join(User.addresses) \
    .options(joinedload(Product.cases)).all()
```

This time the performance is way much better. However, I am not convinced that this is the correct to do it. I am not sure if the caches of tags will be expired when the session ends.

Please let me know the appropriate way for this kind of query. Thank you!

Comment: For the reader's reference, what are you trying to get as output?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship, it's (usually) better to use [`subqueryload`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.subqueryload) instead, for performance reasons:

```
session.query(Product).join(User.addresses)\
    .options(subqueryload(Product.orders),\
             subqueryload(Product.tags)).all()
```

This issues separate `SELECT` queries for each of `orders` and `tags`.

Comment: Is there a way to do it so that multiple queries aren't emitted? It seems like that would add overhead.

Comment: @heplat The whole point is that multiple queries is more efficient than a single query with joins. And no, you can't have the best of both worlds because SQL doesn't work that way.