# Any way to batch load the data in SQLAlchemy's relationships?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So, using `SQLAlchemy`'s [Many-To-Many example](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) (with 1 extra table),

```
class ExternalString(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    string = Column(String(50))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.string


association_table = Table(
    'association', Base.metadata,
    Column('left_id', Integer, ForeignKey('left.id')),
    Column('right_id', Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'))
)


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    name_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(ExternalString.id))
    name = relationship(ExternalString)

    children = relationship("Child", secondary=association_table)


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    name_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(ExternalString.id))
    name = relationship(ExternalString)
```

If you do something like below,

```
for p in Parent.query.all():
    print(p.name)
    for child in p.children:
        print(child.name)
```

I'm ok with the `query.all()` SQL call to the `Parent` table, but every time you print out a parent or child name, that's another SQL call to the `ExternalString` table, and then there's another SQL call when you access any parent rows `children`. Debug output below,

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT `right`.id AS right_id, `right`.name_id AS right_name_id 
FROM `right`, association 
WHERE %s = association.left_id AND `right`.id = association.right_id

INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT external_strings.id AS external_strings_id, external_strings.string AS external_strings_string 
FROM external_strings 
WHERE external_strings.id = %s
```

What I'm asking, after I've got all the parent rows, is there any way I can instruct SQLAlchemy to do a batch operation for getting all the parent's children?

The internal operation is doing a fairly straightforward call to get the children, and what I'd like to instruct SQLAlchemy to do is populate all the parent rows children in 1 SQL call, rather than 1 call per parent.

After that point (I understand this might be a little too much to ask for for a Many-To-Many relationship), when we have all the parents, and their children, is there any way to populate all the `ExternalString` fields that are currently unloaded?

In a perfect world, what I'd like to do is something like this for the children,

```
session.load_all_unloaded(Child)
```

or,

```
session.load_all_unloaded(association_table)
```

and for the strings,

```
session.load_all_unloaded(ExternalString)
```

And what that would do is, via the session's `identity_map`, get all fields that point to Child / relationship to Child, and ExternalString that are currently unloaded, and do a batch SQL call to get them from the DB, and populate those fields, like what would happen in a single call.

Overall, in this situation, if I've 3 parents, each with 2 children, instead of it making 13 SQL calls (1 parents call, 3 parent-children calls, 3 parent name calls, 6 child-name calls), I think it should only be making 3 calls - 1 parents call, 1 children call for all parents, 1 name for all parents and children.

Is there any way to do this, with SQLAlchemy currently?

Comment: Are you looking for eager loading, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886407/sqlalchemy-eager-loading-multiple-relationships ?

Comment: @daveruinseverything I'm not sure. Overall, in this situation, if I've 3 parents, each with 2 children, instead of it making 13 SQL calls (1 parents call, 3 parent-children calls, 3 parent name calls, 6 child-name calls), I think it should only be making 3 calls - 1 parents call, 1 children call for all parents, 1 name for all parents and children.

Comment: The various eager loading strategies allow reducing that to a single query, if need be, but a joined load might not necessarily be the best solution. Read about relationship loading techniques here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html